# DDD how to properly return collections of entities?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have:

```
@DomainAggregate
@Entity
class Meeting {

... more fields here

private Set<AppUser> guests;

public Set<AppUser> getGuests() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(guests);
}
}
```

and `AppUser` is entity (not value object).
I am confused what is correct way of returning collection. 
Is my way correct according to DDD?
(collection cant be modified but, elements of it can)
or maybe I should create dto class for my AppUser objects?
(this will allow me ensure that any data from inside aggregate cant be 
accessed from outside of it but will force few operations more like:
create dto, copy data, etc.)

Comment: Why is it a concern for you if the collection is modifiable or not? It shouldn't matter, since you don't work/modify entities directly and every entity is assigned/changed/mutated through the aggregate. You should never have any reason to persist entities by any other means than through the aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my way correct according to DDD?

According to Evans Chapter 6, it is acceptable.  He wrote (back in 2003)

> Nothing outside the AGGREGATE boundary can hold a reference to anything inside, except to the root ENTITY.  The root ENTITY can hand references to the internal ENTITIES to other objects, but those objects can use them only transiently, and they may not hold on to the reference.
>
> As a corrolary to the previous rule, only AGGREGATE roots can be obtained directly with database queries.  All other objects must be found by traversal of associations.

Comment: is 'transiently' equal to 'use only at method level without storing it as class field value'?

Comment: It is probably more precise to say `not stored in anything that will survive the current transaction`.  When we release the reference to the aggregate root, the entire lot should be eligible for garbage collection.